# Is there any way to toggle Rest template to use Basic Auth or OAuth token?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, oauth, basic-authentication

My Service A makes a GET call to Service B , to get some details . In my code , I've configured below  that builds RestTemplate with Basic Auth creds.

```
@Bean(name=Bobresttemplate)
public RestTemplate resttemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .basicAuthentication("username", "password")
                .build();
    }
```

I use this in my RestClient.Java/ @Service classes by Autowiring.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("Bobresttemplate")
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

My Question : I'm building **`Bobresttemplate`** with Basic Auth , now if I want to use this same Rest template but instead of Basic Auth , I want to use OAuth token to call 3rd party service .I want to acheive a functionality where based on a Toggle , I can use this same **`BobRestTemplate`** but with either of Basic Auth or OAuth .

What extra config do I need to do ? Do I need to create another Bean and build this RestTemplate with OAuth creds ?

I'm looking to understand whether do I need to create another Bean for configuring this template ? Or can I use Interceptors ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpfull to use `spring.profiles` feature:

```
@Profile("basic-auth")
@Bean(name="Bobresttemplate")
public RestTemplate resttemplateBasic(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
            .basicAuthentication("username", "password")
            .build();
}

@Profile("jwt")
@Bean(name="Bobresttemplate")
public RestTemplate resttemplateJwt(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
            ...
            .build();
}
```

so in config you just enable profile that you need (no changes in place of injecting resttemplate bean):

```
spring.profiles.active=jwt
```

or

```
spring.profiles.active=basic-auth
```